# Ensuring new object has a value greater than all others using Rails and Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am creating an auction house similar to eBay. My question is with my bids resource. It will keep track of all of the bids that are placed. However I MUST ensure that every new bid on an item, is higher than the current bid, otherwise that would defeat the purpose of an auction.

The way I currently want to do this is to create a transaction inside the bids controller, that would check whether or not the amount being bid for an item, is greater than the max of the other bids for the same item.

```
def create
    bid.transaction 
      @bid = Bid.new(params[:bid])
      @bid.user = current_user
       @bid.item = current_item
       # DO STUFF TO CHECK ITS GREATER THAN MAX OF BIDS FOR CURRENT_ITEM
       # ON ERROR, ROLLBACK TRANSACTION AND THROW ERROR

    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely handle this in the model.  Create a custom validation such as:

```
#Bid Model
validate :bid_is_higher_than_current_highest

private
def bid_is_higher_than_current_highest
  bid > item.current_highest_bid
end
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First off make sure you're using the `InnoDB` table type as `MyISAM` does not support transactions.

But you're basically right, you just want to run a query inside your transaction to determine the maximum bid:

```
max_bid_amount = Bid.where(:id => item.id).maximum(:bid_amount)
if @bid.bid_amount > max_bid_amount
  # proceed with bid placement
else
  # do something, return some flag, nil or whatever
end
```

Then check the value and proceed accordingly. I would think you would not want to raise an exception for flow control purposes.

I also recommend that you move this logic outside of the controller and either into the Model or some other management layer, maybe have a generic Ruby class like `BidManager` which contains the flow logic for bid placement.